# C++ reading in lines from data file to certain variables

Tags: c++, file, input

I have to read in a list of album names, songs, and year of the album from a data file and then sort the album name alphabetically and the song names within those albums alphabetically. I can read in the entire file but I can't modify the data file for how I usually would do this with arrays.

This is what I have so far.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;



int main() {
int n = 30;
    int albums[n];
    string content;

ifstream infile;
infile.open("BeatlesData.txt");
while (getline(infile,content)) {
cout <<content<< endl;

}
infile.close();
```

This is the data file I'm trying to read from. Each album is separated by "=" also so I have to take that into consideration as well when reading it in.

```
The Beatles White Album 
Year:  1968 
 1. Back in the U.S.S.R.
 2. Dear Prudence
 3. Glass Onion
 4. Ob-La-Di, Ob-La-Da
 5. Wild Honey Pie
 6. The Continuing Story of Bungalow Bill
 7. While My Guitar Gently Weeps
 8. Happiness Is a Warm Gun
 9. Martha My Dear
10. I'm So Tired
11. Blackbird
12. Piggies
13. Rocky Raccoon
14. Don't Pass Me By
15. Why Don't We Do It in the Road?
16. I Will
17. Julia
18. Birthday
19. Yer Blues
20. Mother Nature's Son
21. Everybody's Got Something to Hide Except Me and My Monkey
22. Sexy Sadie
23. Helter Skelter
24. Long, Long, Long
25. Revolution 1
26. Honey Pie
27. Savoy Truffle
28. Cry Baby Cry
29. Revolution 9
30. Good Night 
===============================
Abbey Road 
Year:  1969 
 1. Come Together
 2. Something
 3. Maxwell's Silver Hammer
 4. Oh! Darling
 5. Octopus's Garden
 6. I Want You (She's So Heavy)
 7. Here Comes the Sun
 8. Because
 9. You Never Give Me Your Money
10. Sun King
11. Mean Mr. Mustard
12. Polythene Pam
13. She Came in Through the Bathroom Window
14. Golden Slumbers
15. Carry That Weight
16. The End
17. Her Majesty
===============================
Magical Mystery Tour
Year:  1967 
 1. Magical Mystery Tour
 2. The Fool on the Hill
 3. Flying
 4. Blue Jay Way
 5. Your Mother Should Know
 6. I Am the Walrus
 7. Hello Goodbye
 8. Strawberry Fields Forever
 9. Penny Lane
10. Baby You're a Rich Man
11. All You Need Is Love
=============================== 
Sgt. Pepper's Lonely Hearts Club Band
Year:  1967 
 1. Sgt. Pepper's Lonely Hearts Club Band
 2. With a Little Help from My Friends
 3. Lucy in the Sky With Diamonds
 4. Getting Better
 5. Fixing a Hole
 6. She's Leaving Home
 7. Being for the Benefit of Mr. Kite!
 8. Within You Without You
 9. When I'm Sixty-Four
10. Lovely Rita
11. Good Morning Good Morning
12. Sgt. Pepper's Lonely Hearts Club Band (Reprise)
13. A Day in the Life
=============================== 
Hey Jude
Year:  1970 
 1. Can't Buy Me Love
 2. I Should Have Known Better
 3. Paperback Writer
 4. Rain
 5. Lady Madonna
 6. Revolution
 7. Hey Jude
 8. Old Brown Shoe
 9. Don't Let Me Down
10. The Ballad of John and Yoko
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Your question is "Q: how do I parse this file?"
2. A: You've got a good start - you want to call [std::getline()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/) a line at a time until end of file.
3. `int albums[n];` is a Bad Idea.  What happens if you have 49 albums?  None?  Or, worst of all, 51 albums?  Use [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) instead.
4. The "hard part" is actually parsing each line.  Show us some work, and we'd be happy to answer specific questions on specific problems you encounter.

STRONG SUGGESTION:

- Consider creating an `Album` class.
- Your final result will be `vector<Album>`.
- This hypothetical class might have a public `parseLine(string line)` method to read each line until the album is complete ("===").
- It might also have private `parseTitle()`, `parseYear()` and `parseTrack()` methods to read the input text into the proper class variables.
- It will probably have public properties like `title`, `year` and `vector<Track>`, too.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but I am not going to write your homework assignment for you.

You could try a class album. Make a vector of them. Inside the album class have a vector of class track.
The album class has fields name and year. Tracks have fields number and name.

The first two lines get read into album name and album year. Next read the following lines into a string and if it doesn't start with '=', parse it into track number and name. If you found an equal sign, then start reading the album name and year, unless end of file.

Answer (score 1):

This is not standard C++ :

```
int n = 30;
    int albums[n];
```

you must either change to `const int n`, or preferably use `std::vector<int>`. If `n` is not `const` then you use VLA (variable length array) extension.

As for the parsing, algorithm should be as follows:

1. First line is always a name of CD (right?)
2. Then always comes a year
3. N-times names of songs, until a line containing "======" comes, if so then jump to 1. and until end of file.

So in pseudo code:

```
struct record_type {
   std::string name;
   std::string year;
   std::vector<std::string name> songs;
}
int main() {
// ...
std::vector<record_type> discs;
std::string content;
while(getline(infile,content)) {
    record_type rec;
    rec.name = content;
    if (!getline(infile,content))
      break;
    rec.year = content;
    while (getline(infile,content)) {
      if ( content.find("=====")!=std::string::npos) break;
      rec.songs.push_back(content);
    }
    discs.push_back(rec);
};
}
```

I am not digging into parsing each line, but this is something you can do with [std::stringstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/). For example to parse year:

```
std::stringstream str("Year:  1968 ");
int year;
std::string tmp;
str >> tmp >> year;
```